# How do you change the default browser for Ubuntu / Thunderbird?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, thunderbird

I'm actually not sure if its my default browser for ubunutu that I need to change or just for Thunderbird. I wasn't aware that I could have a default browser for ubuntu but I use firefox and thunderbird opens everything in chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `System -> Preferences -> Preferred Applications`

Got this from here - http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-change-the-default-browser-in-ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 1):

http://appnr.com/package/galternatives
GAlternatives lets you set default browser, this solved the problem for me, some apps still opened firefox instead of chromium after setting the prefered browser via ubuntu menu